# Please recommend a hex editor for shell

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, text-editor

Can you recommend a hex editor that can be run from shell? I need to be able to edit not only view the content.

Comment: I think you can do it using vim

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498197/need-a-good-hex-editor-for-linux

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`emacs` has a hexl-mode for hex editing.

Comment: hexl-mode isn't suitable for large files or disk partitions, since it loads the whole file into an emacs buffer.  It's great for small files if you're already comfortable with emacs.

Comment: @PeterCordes, for editing a disk, simply `dd` the region you want to edit into a file and open that in emacs, then `dd` it back.

Comment: @psusi The problem is, I _shouldn't_ have to go to that effort to edit a file

Comment: @ColeJohnson, we aren't talking about editing a file; we're talking about editing an entire raw hard disk.

Comment: @psusi On my Windows machine, I can use HxD and open up a disk just like any other file.

Answer (score 129):

```
xxd
```

This tool is the most commonly available I have found for this type of task (available by default on both latest Ubuntu and macOS).  You can remove the ascii readable part on the right if needed using `-p` and you can revert (change ascii input to binary data) using the `-r` function.  Here are some simple example uses:

Converting to hex with ascii view:

```
echo example | xxd
```

Converting to a hexdump (no ascii view on the right):

```
echo example | xxd -p
```

Converting from a hexdump back to binary data:

```
echo 746573740a | xxd -p -r
```

You can get much more complex with this in shell scripts.  I have actually used this and "dd" to scan for specific sequences and modify them in a predefined fashion all from a shell script using nothing but bash, `dd`, and `xxd`.  You actually don't need dd for this either as you can "seek" to a specific location and write to that location the byte sequence you need.  The biggest advantage to this approach is its easily scriptable.

Comment: xxd seems to be installed on Ubuntu 16.04 by default, which is SWEET!  Thanks!

Comment: Also available by default on MacOS!

Comment: The `echo` command substitutes newline at the end of the line. To avoid this, you can call the command like this `echo -n example | xxd`

Comment: The question is asking for an editor, not a viewer. xxd is a viewer

Comment: @Baruch `xxd` can convert from binary to human-readable hex and back again, so paired with a regular text editor it can actually cover some use cases for a hex editor.

Comment: I used `xdd -r` to convert a hexdump back to a binary.

Answer (score 41):

There is also [DHEX](http://www.dettus.net/dhex/)

`apt-cache show dhex`

> ncurses based hex editor with diff mode
>
> This is more than just another hex editor: It includes a diff mode,
>   which can be used to easily and conveniently compare two binary files.
>   Since it is based on ncurses and is themeable, it can run on any
>   number of systems and scenarios. With its utilization of search logs,
>   it is possible to track changes in different iterations of files
>   easily.

If you are not familiar with vim or emacs, this one doesn't seem to have much of a learning curve.

Comment: Only downside to dhex imho is it cannot insert/delete bytes. Otherwise it is a very nice console hex editor.

Comment: When I run "dhex /path/to/big/file", I get "error opening inputfile /path/to/big/file". I like dhex and use it all the time for normal sized files.

Comment: @sondra.kinsey : I just tried a 20GB file on my 8GB RAM machine, and didn't have a problem. This is on Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit, with dhex 0.68-2build1 (amd64). So it _should_ work.

Comment: @mivk, I tried dhex unsuccessfully with a 44GB file using dhex_0.68-2build1_i386 on Ubuntu 17.04 with 3GB RAM. hexedit and wxHexEditor open the same file without complaint.

Comment: @sondra.kinsey : maybe a problem/bug with the 32bit version of dhex and files over 4GB?

Answer (score 39):

You might be able to use vi/vim as a hex editor too (it can call xxd).

Enter hex mode:

```
:%!xxd
```

Exit hex mode:

```
:%!xxd -r
```

Source: [Using vi as a hex editor](http://www.kevssite.com/2009/04/21/using-vi-as-a-hex-editor/)

Comment: I'd be careful with that. I've found `:%!xxd` adding new characters(i.e. new line) to the file.

Comment: @iamcreasy it's not `xxd` who does this: rather Vim itself.

Comment: Don't forget to `:set binary`! Otherwise, VIM is likely to corrupt the file by adding a line-end (CR/LF/CRLF) at the end of the file (depending on what you have the format set to (`set ff=[mac/unix/dos]`)). This is highly likely to break executables and data binaries. And it does. A lot. Making sure VIM is in binary mode will prevent that from happening.

Comment: file didn't save and gave conversion error. Even after :set binary

Comment: I would add this link for more info as well: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/343/how-to-edit-binary-files-with-vim

Answer (score 13):

This one is dead simple to use:

```
sudo apt-get install hexcurse
```

Comment: This is the one to beat. All other answers seem like just hex dumps or unnecessary vim acrobatics. Hex editor should have a multiple cursor, one on the hex, and one on the output representation.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old question, but I was dissatisfied with all of the answers here. I was looking for a hex editor that allowed for me to create my own binary files (aka insert mode) and could handle very large files.

I came across [tweak](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/tweak/), which fulfills both of these requirements, as well as the OPs.

> - Tweak supports insert mode (not particularly useful if you're editing an executable file or a filesystem image, but can be extremely
>     handy in other file formats such as PNG).
> - Cutting, copying and pasting within the file you are editing is extremely efficient. No matter how big the chunk of data you are
>     moving around - even if it's a 200Mb section of a CD image - Tweak
>     will always perform the operation effectively instantly.
> - Tweak supports lazy loading of the input file: rather than sucking it all into memory straight away, it simply remembers which parts of
>     the editing buffer are copies of which parts of the input file and
>     refers to the file on disk when it needs to. Tweak only has to take
>     significant time when you genuinely need it to read the entire file.
>     The only two operations with this property are searching, and saving
>     the modified version of the file to disk. Everything else is instant.

Comment: Hmmm, a program that's ready to modify the buffer with every mistaken keystroke, and doesn't instruct the user how (or exit!) to use the program. Yuck!

Turns out the "exit" command is the same as emacs... but it didn't work for me the first time, so I tried everything else I could think of before trying it again. I gave up on emacs decades ago, but remember the most important command: Ctrl-X, Ctrl-C.

If you like emacs, you might like `tweak`, but for me it was awkward. I may try it again if I really need editing. Run `man tweak` from the terminal for an overview and list of commands.

Comment: @Lambart The whole point of tweak's insert mode is to modify the buffer, so your point isn't really valid there. Also, you should read the man page before using it anyway. Not doing so and then complaining that it doesn't tell you how to exit is just lazy.

Answer (score 4):

[Bless Hex Editor](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/editors/bless) is a is a binary (hex) editor and currently provides the following features:

- Efficient editing of large data files and block devices.
- Multilevel undo - redo operations.
- Customizable data views.
- Fast data rendering on screen.
- Multiple tabs.
- Fast find and replace operations.
- A data conversion table.
- Advanced copy/paste capabilities.
- Highlighting of selection pattern matches in the file.
- Plugin based architecture.
- Export of data to text and html (others with plugins).
- Bitwise operations on data.
- A comprehensive user manual.

You can dounload it from here: http://packages.debian.org/sid/all/bless/download.

To install it, see [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-to-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Need more?

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498197/need-a-good-hex-editor-for-linux

Comment: The question is asking for a command line editor.

Comment: @psusi No, the OP asked about *a hex editor that can be run from shell*, **not** *inside* shell/terminal. It can be run from shell using `bless` command after is installed.

Comment: There is nothing you can not run from the shell; he wouldn't have mentioned it unless he meant command line.

Comment: Actually I was searching "ubuntu hex viewer" meaning window-based viewer in mind and the search site brought me here. So this answer was what I had search for.

Answer (score 3):

Try [hexed](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hexed/), it's made for use in scripts and make files.

Answer (score 2):

There is also `ht`. Install it as

```
sudo apt-get install ht
```

and then run it by typing `hte`.

I haven't tried it with really large files/partitions, though.