# How do I change file headers from the command line?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, binary

I have seen and used the GUI hex-editor `bless`, to modify bitmaps to match a separate file type (form bmp to srf). My question is how to modify file headers programmatically with the command line. What programs would allow me to make changes to file headers from  shell script?

I have looked in synaptic package manager, but I'm new to modifying files in hex. Do bitmaps count as binary files?  Where this is a software recommendation request, an acceptable answer would allow  me to write, overwrite, or change specific values to specific locations (such as the first 16 bytes of a file), in the command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xxd` is a very powerful command-line hex editor which allows you to change binary files with a single command line. You can use it this way:

```bsh
xxd -r -p -o OFFSET <(echo NEW HEX SIGNATURE) FILE  # or
echo NEW HEX SIGNATURE | xxd -r -p -o OFFSET - FILE
```

Let's “convert” `01.png` file to rar format (hex signature `5261 7221 1A07 0000`, offset `0`<sup>1</sup>):

```
$ file 01.png 
01.png: PNG image data, 1280 x 1024, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
$ xxd 01.png | head -1
00000000: 8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a 0000 000d 4948 4452  .PNG........IHDR
$ xxd -r -p -o 0 <(echo 5261 7221 1A07 0000) 01.png
$ file 01.png 
01.png: RAR archive data, vdb, os: MS-DOS
$ xxd 01.png | head -1
00000000: 5261 7221 1a07 0000 0000 000d 4948 4452  Rar!........IHDR
```

See [`man xxd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xxd.1.html) for other useful options and lots of helpful examples.

<sup><sup>1</sup>If the offset is `0` the option `-o` can be omitted, I include it here only to show its usage.</sup>

If you like it better you can do the truncating with `dd` as well, but that seems unnecessarily complicated:

```
dd conv=notrunc obs=1 if=<(xxd -r -p -o 0 <(echo 5261 7221 1A07 0000)) of=01.png
```

Further reading (besides [usual command-line help](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/507051)):

- [Please recommend a hex editor for shell – `xxd` answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/573570/507051)
- [Change the header in a huge file without rewriting the whole file
  · SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27265904/6164712)
- [Wikipedia's List of file signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)